# In which episode do they say, that from the outside the Straw Hats don't look like a team?

Tags: one-piece

During the Alabasta Arc, in episode 102, Zoro tells Chopper that

> "someone once said, that from the outside, we don't look like a team."

But who originally told this to the Straw Hats and in which episode did this happen?

Comment: can you tell us which episode Zoro said that to Chopper?

Comment: the comments in this youtube link say episode 102: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prxqDQoP6BE)

Comment: After seeing that clip it makes we wonder again what the other purpose is that emerged for Zorro to be part of the crew. ontopic: I think Zorro was being speaking in general, although knowing Oda, someone might have actually said it though. So I hope someone finds it.

Comment: Yes, that "other purpose" would be a another interesting question.

Comment: If I remember correctly it was Kuma who said this to zoro. But I ain't to sure.

Comment: @Dimitrimx, they meet Kuma after a lot of arcs. (Gecko Moriah)
Because I am reading the manga, I haven't seen anyone said it like that.
I think it's just what most of the people they met until then were thinking, that didn't believe they could actually help each other. For example in the fight of Luffy with Arlong he threw Zoro away like that.. so it makes sense then some to say somethink like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure but I think that episode in which Zoro makes the statement is non-canon. I tried checking up the manga chapters of the Arabasta arc and was unable to find it. Thus I think it was just one of those cool things that Zoro said that isn't actually official.